# How to query a class and check if a key is null or a value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, constraints, pfquery

I have a class that has a column that can be either null, or the user.
If null, it means it is an app default object, if not null, it was a user created object.

**How can I setup the query to use BOTH those constraints so that all 'app created' records AND 'currentUser' created records are returned?**

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "MyClass")
    query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("createdBy")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out using subqueries:

```
    var defaultQuery = PFQuery(className: "MyClass")
    defaultQuery.whereKeyDoesNotExist("createdBy")

    var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "MyClass")
    userQuery.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([defaultQuery, userQuery])
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you add more conditions to the query?

Try:

```
query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser() || nil))
```

Comment: That would just use either PFUser.currentUser() or nil if it didn't exist. I want to actually get all records that A) Have 'nil' (undefined) as the createdBy AND B) Were created by the currentUser.

Comment: so you want the results separate by created by user and created by app?

Comment: No. I want them combined in one query call. "Get all records created by app and all records created by the current user". Figured out one way to do it. See my answer below.